# Php is printing only one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

As you can see, i'm selecting user from data base, but its only printing one!
I have like 10 users that needs to be printed.

```php
<?php
      session_start();
      $currentgroup = $_SESSION['groupname'];
      $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM hjuma_users WHERE group1 ='$currentgroup' OR group2 ='$currentgroup' OR group3 ='$currentgroup' OR group4 ='$currentgroup' OR group5 ='$currentgroup';";
      if($result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0){
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ ?>


<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <?php echo $row1['username']; ?>

    </div>


  </form>
</div>
<?php   }
      }
    }
      ?>
```

Comment: Just a note that each row will have `<div id="id01"`, so the id will be repeated and then you use `getElementById('id01')` which will have a few to choose from.

Comment: i dont understand, can you give me some code for example? i think that is the problem, how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you echo record's data without HTML?

Comment: yes i can, i just tried it

Comment: According to the php documentation there is no function `mysqli_fetch_array()`, so I'm surprised you even get one result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` as below code:

```
session_start();
$currentgroup = $_SESSION['groupname'];
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM hjuma_users WHERE group1 ='$currentgroup' OR group2 ='$currentgroup' OR group3 ='$currentgroup' OR group4 ='$currentgroup' OR group5 ='$currentgroup';";
if ($result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        $modalId = 1;
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
            <div id="id<?php echo $modalId; ?>" class = "modal">
            <form class = "modal-content animate" action = "/action_page.php">
            <div class = "imgcontainer">
            <span onclick = "document.getElementById('id<?php echo $modalId; ?>').style.display='none'" class = "close" title = "Close Modal">&times;
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class = "container">
            <?php echo $row1['username'];
?>

            </div>


            </form>
            </div>
        <?php
        $modalId++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) returns all rows in one call.

Comment: have you tried mysql_fetch_assoc?? Please check the updated answer. Also, if it doesn't work, then you should print your query directly and try to execute that in sql directly. May be your query is only returning one row

Comment: I did print my query directly and it worked, but it doesnt work inside a modal, how is that possible.... Inside the modal its printing only one user, but outside all of them..

Comment: @RohitMittal `mysql_fetch_array` is not compatible with `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @JurajJaušovec use mysqli_fetch_assoc array as above updated answer. I have checked it and it is working fine on my system.

Comment: @JurajJaušovec to get working modal, you should have different key for each modal popup. Need to alter code for div id and javascript code. You can use key or a variable which will change value in every iteration and you can make id by concating that variable.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are not incrementing $result1

Comment: Using `mysqli_fetch_array()` will automatically move the result set onto the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of $currentgroup.

If you can give the screenshot of the database table hjuma_users and the value of $currentgroup.

I think you are getting one value due to the condition

```
WHERE group1 ='$currentgroup' OR group2 ='$currentgroup' OR group3 ='$currentgroup' OR group4 ='$currentgroup' OR group5 ='$currentgroup
```